# Changing Producer Count on Private Blockchain

Tags: block-producer, private-blockchain

In a private EOS blockchain environment (think company/industry specific), is there a way to change the number of block producers in the network to be more than the 21 used in the public blockchain?  If I am working in an industry that has, say, 40 players, can I configure the blockchain so that each of the 40 players can be a producer on the network?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/905e7c85714aee4286fa180ce946f15ceb4ce73c/testnet.md) and [this](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/0f6695cb8d31e3d2f318d1720e9d9ad23e1ce80d/programs/eosio-launcher) used to help with this, but not sure if they're still actively maintained at the moment

Answer (score 2):

You can change number of BPs in system contract,

Change "21" to your desired number as below:

refer:eos/contracts/eosio.system/voting.cpp

```
top_producers.reserve(**21**);

  for ( auto it = idx.cbegin(); it != idx.cend() && top_producers.size() < **21** && 0 < it->total_votes && it->active(); ++it ) {
     top_producers.emplace_back( std::pair<eosio::producer_key,uint16_t>({{it->owner, it->producer_key}, it->location}) );
  }
```