# How many requirement to make EOS testnet

Tags: cleos, nodeos, block-producer, eosio.token, testnet

I have made my local EOS testnet. Almost I followed the Bios Boot Sequence Pages. So I made a "eosio" account and created two block producers that were registered in chain. So three were created.

But BP(block producer) couldn't produce blocks just receive blocks from eosio account.

I find some sentences in the EOS page that:

> chapter3
>
> ...
>   Once producers have been elected and **the minimum number requirements**
>   have been met, that is minimum 15% of tokens have been staked to
>   producers votes, the account can resign, leaving the account as the
>   only privileged account.

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence

Is there rule of "the minimum number requirements"??

Comment: The quote you got there already says that the requirement is that **15% of tokens have to be staked for votes**. Do tokens exist in your testnet and have you voted with at least 15% for the two BPs?

Comment: Hmm maybe not but I got a better idea that changes the BP count. https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/changing-producer-count-on-private-blockchain

Comment: The quote you have above is wrong. I know that's what it says, but the system is lying. It isn't checking for 15% of tokens to be staked, it is checking for 150M of tokens to be staked. Ensure that you issue and stake over 150M tokens to activate your local testnet for block production. I have filed an issue on the `eosio.system` contract to have this addressed. **You do not need to change number of BPs**